# How to check connection pool settings values of spring boot application w/ multiple data sources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection, spring-boot-actuator

I do have spring boot application using spring data jpa. I am connecting to multiple data sources ( different databases ). I want to check connection pool settings values for both of the data sources.

What is the easiest way to do the same.

I am using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE. My database is DB2.

Answer (score 2):

In general for Application:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
        }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);

    }
}
```

for Test:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BankConceptTests {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);
        assertEquals("com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource", dataSource.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

**DataBaseRepository** exemplary class to print connection pooling details:

```
package com.threadminions.service;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DatabaseRepository {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    /***
     * If you are using DBCP connection pooling then use this method to get the connection details
     */
    /*public void printDBCPConnectionDetails()
    {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = (BasicDataSource) dataSource;
        System.out.println("Instace of DBCP basic data source: " + basicDataSource);
        System.out.println("Driver class name: " + basicDataSource.getDriverClassName());
        System.out.println("Max idle connection: " + basicDataSource.getMaxIdle());
        System.out.println("Total connection: " + basicDataSource.getMaxTotal());
    }*/

    /***
     * If using Hikari connection pooling
     */
    /*public void printHikariConnectionDetails()
    {
        HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource)dataSource;
        System.out.println("Instace of DBCP basic data source: " + ds);
        System.out.println("Driver class name: " + ds.getDriverClassName());
        System.out.println("Connection Pool size : " + ds.getMaximumPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Url: " + ds.getJdbcUrl());

    }*/

    /***
     * If using C3P0 connection pooling
     */
    /*public void printC3P0ConnectionDetails()
    {
        ComboPooledDataSource ds = (ComboPooledDataSource) dataSource;
        System.out.println("Instace of DBCP basic data source: " + ds);
        System.out.println("Connection Pool size : " + ds.getMaxPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Min connection pool size: " + ds.getMinPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Max statements: " + ds.getMaxStatements());
        System.out.println("Url: " + ds.getJdbcUrl());
    }*/
}
```

See details: https://threadminions.com/2017/12/25/spring-boot-with-different-connection-pooling/